# Backup/Restore on CloudSQL instances

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, database-backups, tunnel

We have plans of migrating our `CloudSQL` instances from `Public to Private IP`. Since we are migrating to `Private IP` on a `SharedVPC` which is yet to be supported by Google for existing instances, we plan to create new instances with a `private IP` on a `sharedVPC` and restore backup from old instance .
Following are my queries based on the scenario.

1. Any way to check the size of existing databases in `CloudSQL instances` ?
2. Where the backup is stored. Is it `Cloud Storage` or the `DB disk` ?
3. Can we access the `CloudSQL instance with a private IP` from my `desktop` using `IAP tunneling` ?

Clarifications please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I address you questions:

**1. Any way to check the size of existing databases in CloudSQL instances?**

Yes, there is. This depends on the database engine you are using(mysql, postgres or mssql)

For **mysql**, you can run:

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name",
        ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

For **postgres**, you can run:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('Database Name'));
```

For **mssql**, you can run:

```
SELECT 
      database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID() -- for current db 
GROUP BY database_id
```

**2.Where the backup is stored? Is it Cloud Storage or the DB disk?**

Cloud Storage. When you [make a Cloud SQL export](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting), the export file is
stored in Cloud Storage. From Cloud Storage, you can download/move
it to a different location.

**3. Can we access the CloudSQL instance with a private IP from my desktop using IAP tunneling ?**

No, the IAP tunneling aka IAP for TCP forwarding is intended to be used with Google Cloud compute engine instances.
Quoting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tcp-forwarding-overview#how-tcp-forwarding-works):

> IAP's TCP forwarding feature allows users to connect to arbitrary TCP
> ports on Compute Engine instances.

There is also [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/176209851) to extend the capabilities of IAP TCP forwarding to cover Cloud SQL instances. I would recommend then to star the issue tracker and share your feedback so that the thread relevance increases.

An alternative to connect to a Cloud SQL instance with only private ip, would be to use a bastion host with an external public address that forwards all TCP traffic to your Cloud SQL instance.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks so much Antonio. That helps. For 2nd scenario , i am talking of the automated backups where they are stored ?

Comment: Please have a look at this section, it answers your question :). If you need info regarding the other engines(mysql & mssql) you can go to the top of the page and switch the document.  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/backups#where_backups_are_stored